# Control DC gear motor using a rotary encoder

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a rotary encoder and a DC gear motor connected to my Arduino UNO. I would like to rotate the DC motor at a certain angle. As I right now, I have written a code that reads the position of my encoder as I rotate it and prints out the position and the angle. I have also written code that runs the dc motor at fixed amount of time.

**I would like to rotate the dc motor at a certain angle. For example, if I input 90 degrees my motor should rotate 90 degrees and stop.**

- I'm using pin 2 and pin 3 for my channel A and B (ENCODER)
- I'm using pin 9 to control my dc motor.

I have no clue how to approach this... any thoughts?

```
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

    LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    int lcd_case = 0;
    volatile int timeToRun = 0;
    int motorPin = 6;


    #define BTN_RIGHT 0
    #define BTN_LEFT 1
    #define BTN_UP 2
    #define BTN_DOWN 3
    #define BTN_SELECT 4
    #define BTN_NONE 5
    #define SELECT 6
    #define RESET 7
    #define PIN 


    #define encoderPinA 2
    #define encoderPinB 3
    #define CPR 256
    volatile int counter =0;
    volatile boolean flag;

    volatile int var_degrees =0;

    void setup() {
      pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

      pinMode(encoderPinA, INPUT);
      pinMode(encoderPinB, INPUT);
      Serial.begin (9600);
      attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPinA), isr_2, RISING);
      lcd.clear();

    }

    void loop() {

       if(flag == true){     
            var_degrees = ((360/256.0)*counter);
            Serial.println(var_degrees);
            //lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
            //lcd.print("Degrees: ");
            //lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
            //lcd.print(var_degrees);
            flag = false;
      }

      lcd_case = readButtons();
      int  read_button = analogRead (0);
      //Depending on which button we pressed, we performan action
      switch (lcd_case) {

        case BTN_RIGHT:
          {
            break;
          }

        case BTN_LEFT:
          {
            break;
          }
        case BTN_UP:
          {

            timeToRun = timeToRun +1;

            lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
            lcd.print("Degrees: ");
            lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
            lcd.print(timeToRun);
            delay(500);
            break;

          }
        case BTN_DOWN:
          {

            if (timeToRun > 0) {
              timeToRun = timeToRun - 1;

              lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
              lcd.print("Degrees: ");
              lcd.setCursor(9, 1);
              lcd.print(timeToRun);
              delay(500);
              break;

            }

          }

        case BTN_SELECT:
          {

            analogWrite(motorPin, 255);
  // I NEED TO ROTATE MOTOR BASED ON ANGLE IN ENCODER

        delay(timeToRun * 100); //ONLY ROTATES DC MOTOR IN SECONDS
            break;

          }

        case RESET:
          {
            break;
          }
      }

    }
    //Interrupts 

    void isr_2(){


    flag = true;
      if(digitalRead(encoderPinA) == HIGH){
        if(digitalRead(encoderPinB) == LOW){
          counter = counter -1; //COUNTER CLOCK WISE
        }
        else{
          counter = counter +1; //CLOCK WISE
        }
      }
      else{ //IF PIN A IS LOW
        if(digitalRead(encoderPinB) == LOW){
          counter = counter +1; //CLOCK WISE
        }
        else{
          counter = counter -1 ; //COUNTER CLOCK WISE
        }
      }
    }



    int readButtons() {

      int read_button;
      read_button = analogRead (0);

      if (read_button < 50) {
        return BTN_RIGHT;
      }
      if (read_button < 195) {

        return BTN_UP;

      }
      if (read_button < 400) {
        return BTN_DOWN;

      }
      if (read_button < 600) {
        return BTN_LEFT;
      }
      if (read_button < 800) {
        return BTN_SELECT;
      }
      else
        return BTN_NONE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you are correctly reading the position of the armature of your motor. Now is the time to use PID and closed loop! Tuned PID is a controller that helps your motor to go to the desired position at the best possible time with the lowest possible overshoot(error) It takes a control course to learn all of this. You will basically need a feedback loop that takes the "desired angle", give it to the controller which moves the motor. Then you get the current position of the motor, which will be fed back to the origin of the system. Your "desired angle" minus "current angle" will be how much your motor should move each time the micro controller go over the loop. 
Here is how the feedback loop looks like:
[image]

And here is link to learn control. Good luck!
[Control Tutorials](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlPID)

Edit 2: I should probably give you an intro on what PID is as well. PID controller is made of three different components:

1. Proportional
2. Integral
3. Derivative

Each time you get your "Desired Angle" - "Actual Angle" or "e" as shown in diagram, you will times it by Kp. Find its derivative with respect to previous e and times it by Kd, and find the integral of the errors and times it by Ki. You can start by ignoring Ki and integral, and add it if it was needed later. After you got Kp*e+Kd*d(e)/dt,  this values is the percentage of power you will output to your motor. Kp and Kd and Ki is where the real engineering comes into play. You should find them using the transfer function of your system and fine-tune them in MatLab or a similar software. These values are usually low (less than 1). It really depends on your system. For my motor, they were Kp=0.001 and Kd=0.02

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is actually really helpful! I am actually not reading the position of the armature of my motor. I am reading the position of my optical incremental encoder and converting the position in degrees. I have the encoder and a dc motor connected to Arduino.  I have a couple of questions for you : my variable var_degrees holds the degrees as I rotate my encoder.   so going along of what you said my desired angle will be my var_degrees. I do not have the current position of my motor. so what would be the actual angle? the position of my motor?

Comment: The DC motor and the encoder are not together. they are separate. Somehow I thought that reading the position of my encoder will help me achieve what I need. If I read the position of my encoder. How can I tell my motor to turn/rotate whatever position I read from my encoder. Encoder is not attached to motor. I do not understand the relationship between motor and encoder.

Comment: No worries, I had a hard time learning this topic few years ago as well :) So back to encoder, it is there to serve as the position sensor for your motor. I am not sure how exactly your encoder looks like, but usually it is a disk that gets attached to the armature of your motor. As you rotate the armature you get pulses which can be converted to angle in the code. You probably need to get that working before anything else.

Comment: If you search online for how to use optical encoders and Arduino, you will find it. After that, your desired angle would be the goal, what you wanna reach. And the actual angle would be your reading from the encoder. You subtract them from each other, and you get the angle is left for you to go to get to your goal.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah my encoder is not attach to the motor. I am going to have a magnetic encoder that will be attach to my motor later. For now, I just want to rotate the encoder, in other words as I am rotating the encoder the dc motor will be rotating too. I saw a few videos online doing that but they used a L298N H-Bridge. Is it possible to achieve that without using a bridge. My new question is : how do I send the data (angle reading from encoder) to dc motor.

Comment: Here is the video as a reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIq-sIvN080  and here is the code the used : https://github.com/raydike/PID_position_OK/blob/test1/PID_position_OK.ino

Comment: So you read the angle, use PID to figure out how much power you should apply, and apply it as Pulse Width Modulation. According to the link that you sent,  the pwmOut function is what make your motor moves.  You will need a H-bridge for that. You can either make one using components (you can search online for how to) or you can use L298N.( which is easier)